# Validating a textbox entry if duplicate display error message microsoft access

Tags: vba, ms-access

i have searched around and cant find an answer, so i am using Microsoft Access Office 2019 and cant seem to validate my textbox for a duplicate entry. The user will add a record and enter a short text primary key (which in this case is the new employee's ID) Field - [EMPID] in the [EMPDETAILS] table. The below code has worked for validating my Autonumber primary key but doesnt seem to work for a custom short text primary key and i am getting this error

> "The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error :
>   'VS123'

<= this is the Employee ID which is a custom short text primary key :

```
Private Sub unqidd_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

Dim strMessage As String
'PartNum is the name of a textbox that contains the primary key, the rest are text to display.
strMessage = "Employee ID" & Me!unqidd & " already exists."

' confirm that part number doesn't already exist.
If (DLookup("[empid]", "[empdetails]", "[empID] = " & Forms![driverdetails]![unqidd])) Then
    MsgBox strMessage, vbInformation, "Invalid Operation"
    Cancel = True
End If
Exit_Here:
Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_Here

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the field `[empID]` numeric as most ID fields are? Or is it a String?

Comment: It is a String (Short Text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as below :

1) Create an unbound textbox (Text1616) and set its control source as

```
=DLookUp("[empid]","[empdetails]","[empID] = '" & [Forms]![Driverdetails]![unqidd] & "'")
```

2) The textbox (Unqidd) that will need to be validated, on its beforeupdate property set the event procedure code as below :

```
Private Sub unqidd_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

Dim strMessage As String
'PartNum is the name of a textbox that contains the primary key, the rest are text to 
display.
strMessage = "Employee ID" & Me!unqidd & " already exists."

' confirm that part number doesn't already exist.
If Me.unqidd.Value = Me.Text1616 Then
    MsgBox strMessage, vbInformation, "Invalid Operation"
    Cancel = True
End If

Exit_Here:
Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_Here

End Sub


'References :
'Table Name        : empdetails
'Table primary key : empid (Short text)
'Form Name         : Driverdetails
'Textbox 1         : unqidd (no formats, control source : empid)
'Textbox 2         : Text1616 (Unbound Textbox)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to add a string into `[empID]` I am going to assume it is a string field, in which case you need to include quotes:

```
If (DLookup("[empid]", "[empdetails]", "[empID] = '" & Forms![driverdetails]![unqidd] & "'")) Then
```

Comment: It Returns "Type Mismatch"

Comment: What does `MsgBox "[empID] = '" & Forms![driverdetails]![unqidd] & "'"` return?

Comment: Btw, i removed the "[ ] " from driverdetails and unqidd  Forms!driverdetails!unqidd

Comment: it returns "type mismatch"

Comment: Then the problem is `Forms!driverdetails!unqidd` - Did you spell everything right? Get that message box code working and then the rest will work.

Comment: For example, what is the `Name` of the textbox on that form?

Comment: The textbox name is "unqidd " its control source is "empID" no formats.

Comment: Thank you very much @brax i just thought of an alternative and it works !!

Comment: What was the working alternative? Remember, future readers will want to know how you solved it.

Comment: Also, please remember to accept the answer so that the question does not remain open.